# How to get env from mongosh shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I need to get an environment variable from `mongosh`.

In the old mongo shell I could do it with the [`_getEnv` method](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/shell_utils_extended.cpp#L663) like this `_getEnv("MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE")`.

That shell is [removed from MongoDB 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-mongo-shell-removed). So I can only use `mongosh` shell in mongo 6.0 and higher. However, there is no `_getEnv` method in `mongosh` so I get an error: `ReferenceError: getenv is not defined`.

I can't find how to access env from the new shell neither in documentation nor in source.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the way one can access env variables in Node.js also works in mongosh (as stated [in the doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/): mongosh is a fully functional JavaScript and Node.js 16.x REPL environment).

So the syntax `process.env.ENV_NAME` will work.